# Checking if user input contains an item

Tags: java

In my text-adventure game one of the commands is *"take"* which requires the user to enter both the letter *'T'* and an item that is in the room they are in.
I have taken this input and split it into command and item, but I'm having trouble with the if statement. I have the first part that checks if the command section is equal to 'T', but I have to also check if this input has an "item" section to it. I tried using `.isEmpty()` and `!= null` as well as using `.contains()`.

Here is my code:

```
public Command getCommandFromResponse(String response) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    String[] split = response.split(" ");

    if (split.length < 1){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid command.");
    }

    Command command = new Command(split[0]);
    if (split.length >= 2) {
        command.setItem(split[1]);
    }
    return command;
}
```

This is the take method:

```
else if(userCommand.command.equalsIgnoreCase("T") && /*if userCommand contains an item*/){                 
    //Split the input String into two parts, command and item
    userCommand = getCommandFromResponse(userInput.nextLine());
    if (locale.item != null) {
        if (userCommand.item.equalsIgnoreCase(locale.item.itemName)) {
            //add the item to the player's inventory
            player1.inventory.add(locale.item);
            System.out.println("\tA " + locale.item + " was added to your inventory");
            System.out.println("\n\tYou can view your inventory by pressing 'I' or drop an item by pressing 'D'.");
            if (locale.item.itemName.equals("map")) {
                System.out.println("\n\tTo view the map press 'M'.");
            }
            //Add the item's worth to the score and set the items worth to zero to prevent double scoring
            player1.score += locale.item.value;
            System.out.println("\n\t" + locale.item.value + " points have been added to your score.");
            System.out.println("\n\tThis is your current score: "+player1.score);
            //remove the item from the current location
            locale.item = null;
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("\n\tThat item is not at this location.");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("\n\tThere is no item to pick up here");
    }
}//End of Take
```

This is my Command class:

```
public class Command {

    String command;
    String item;
    public Command(String comm){
        command = comm;
    }

    public Command(String comm, String item){
        this.command = comm;
        this.item = item;
    }

    public void setCommand(String command){
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void setItem(String item){
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getCommand(){
        return this.command;
    }

    public String getItem(){
        return this.item;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.command + ":" + this.item;
    }

}
```

These are my items:

```
//Items {itemName, itemDes}
    static Item[] items = {
            new Item ("map","a layout of your house", 10 ),
            new Item ("battery", "a double A battery", 5),
            new Item ("flashlight", "a small silver flashlight", 10),
            new Item ("key", "this unlocks some door in your house", 15),
    };
```

I have more code if this is unclear.

Comment: How do you have the all items stored? A list? Enum?

Comment: I have an Item class and the Items are stored in an array of Item. I added them to my code above :)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If the user enters for example: t map, then it will say invalid command in my game. If I user userCommand.item != null then I get a nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to do it the following way:

change

```
if (userCommand.item.equalsIgnoreCase(locale.item.itemName)) {
```

to

```
if (userCommand.item!=null && userCommand.item.equalsIgnoreCase(locale.item.itemName)) {
```

This is the simplest way, which won't throw an exception if there was no item in the command.

(I'm sorry if this was not your question, but this is the problem what I think you mean.)

Comment: Thank you, the only problem is that I must first check both for t and if a second word was entered after it and then the next step is to check if the second word entered was an item that is present in the room. By using the userCommand.item != null I was getting a nullpointerexception.

Comment: If you're getting a ´NullPointerException´ exactly at this place (at `userCommand.item`), there seems to be a problem with ´userCommand´. Check if it has been correctly initialized.

Comment: When I enter the command into my game and hit enter there will be a blank space and if I again hit enter then it will come up with the exception, so I'm a little lost as to where I'm going wrong

Comment: I think this line is the problem:
`else if(userCommand.command.equalsIgnoreCase("T") && /*if userCommand contains an item*/){                 
    //Split the input String into two parts, command and item
    userCommand = getCommandFromResponse(userInput.nextLine());`

userCommand seems to be initialized in the `else if`-clause. After that, you read a second time the input (`userInput.nextLine()`) which would obviously return only an empty line.

I suggest to just remove this line:
`userCommand = getCommandFromResponse(userInput.nextLine());`